# When is question deletion vandalism?

Tags: discussion

In the past (I have no examples on hand), sometimes when an OP deletes a question it's un-deleted, with the rationale that the content offers value to StackExchange and deleting it thus constitutes vandalism.

When is this the case - when there are answers? Or different criteria? Does https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/269132/parse-csv-file-from-bytes apply?

Comment: Related: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/269301), [When should I vote to delete a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58842/269301) "Questions should be deleted when their content no longer adds anything to the site." If the content still adds anything to the site (which is usually the case with answered questions), it could be vandalism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users' posts (on Stack Exchange) have been undeleted due to "vandalism". This can be when a user rage-quits the site and deletes all their posts.
A post can be rolled back when a user defaces the post, for example  editing a post to contain inappropriate images.

However these instances of vandalism are mostly related to answers, because the system doesn't allow users to delete many questions. I can only recall two times when users have undeleted a question, both spawning from my question [Asker deletes question after posting an answer](/q/9165). With the conclusion you can vote to undelete anything you want, just like the OP can vote to delete anything they want.

However, I think we should only undelete questions with answers. For example, where both 301 and I posted an answer and our time and effort was unilaterally deleted by the OP.

Comment: Note that it's hard to unilaterally delete answered questions as the question owner. The incident you recalled had the small wrinkle that the answers did not gather any upvotes yet (IINM)

Comment: @Vogel612 Yes, I tried to allude to that here; "Because the system doesn't allow users to delete many questions." Should I perhaps rephrase to emphasis better?